# Call PHP SoapServer function with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, soap

I am attempting to use PHP 5.2's SoapServer functionality. I setup soapserv.php as shown below. But I am lost as to how I can call the 'add' function with a language other than PHP (without WSDL). I want to make calls to it with AJAX (jQuery). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
    function add($a, $b) {
      return $a + $b;
    }

  $soap = new SoapServer(
    null,
    array('uri' => 'http://example.com/projects/php/soapserv/')
  );
  $soap->addFunction("add");
  $soap->handle();
?>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this (tried several ways though).

```
var req = $.post("http://example.com/projects/php/soapserv", {"add":{a: 1, b: 2}});

            req.done(function(msg){
                document.write(msg.responseText);
            });

            req.fail(function(msg){
                document.write(msg.responseText);
            });
```

Comment: Well, you are going to have to send a SOAP request to your SOAP service, and the service will interpret it, do some stuff, and send a response. Whether or not this code does that, I do not know.

Comment: Ajax can't be done cross domain. You should try and do all the soap stuff in a php script and then make the ajax request to the php script.

Comment: SOAP is not just POST request.

Comment: Its odd because if you create a .NET soap service, you can post to it just like you would a php script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... Just had to change the post data to a soap envelope!

```
        var request = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
        request += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n";
        request += "<soap:Body xmlns:m=\"http://example.com/projects/php/soapserv\">\n";
        request += "<m:add>\n";
        request += "<m:a>1</m:a>\n";
        request += "<m:b>2</m:b>\n";
        request += "</m:add>\n";
        request += "</soap:Body>\n";
        request += "</soap:Envelope>";

        var req = $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://example.com/projects/php/soapserv",
           data: request,
           cache: false
        });
```